# Template instantiation for type string, but operator overload method gives an error no operator "[]" matches these operands Templates

Tags: c++, class, templates, arguments

```
    template <typename T, size_t SIZE>
    struct Array
    {
        const T* data() const
        {
            return std::addressof(m_data[0]);
        }

        constexpr size_t size() const 
        {
            return SIZE;
        }

        T* begin() { return data(); }
        T* end() { return data() + size(); }
        T& operator[] (size_t id) { return m_data[id]; }

        T m_data[SIZE];
    }

int main()
{
    Array<int, 3> intArray{ 2, 4, 5 };
    Array<double, 2> doArray{ 3.0, 4 };
    int value = intArray[0];

    const Array<std::string, 2> strArray {"S", "R"};
    const auto strData = strArray.data();
    std::cout << *strData;

    //auto secondStr = strArray[0];
    /* for(const auto& x: strArray)
    {
        std::cout << x;
    }*/


}
```

I am learning templates, not sure why I am getting an error while trying to strArray[0]  "no operator "[]" matches these operands" for strings whereas it works fine for both int and double types above.

Tried with int and double that worked but not sure why it doesnt work with strings

Comment: When posting questions about build errors, first make sure that the code you show is a proper [mre] that actually replicates the error you ask about. Then copy-paste (as text) the full and complete build log into the question, it could contain informational messages or notes that helps with understanding the error. Lastly add comments on the lines in the shown code where you get the errors.

Comment: You need a `const` overload for the operator if you want to be able to call it with `const` objects. For future questions, make sure to include complete error message as part of [mcve].

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them.

Comment: Refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) where the first step is to *"search and then research"* and you'll find plenty of related SO posts for this.